# Как связать динамическую форму и модель в ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Есть такая модель.

```
public class FormModel
{
    public string FormTitle { get; set; }
    public string FormDescription { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BlockWorkingFieldForm> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class BlockWorkingFieldForm
{
    public string FieldHeader { get; set; }
    public string FieldType { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public bool FieldQuestion { get; set; }
}
```

И есть форма, она состоит из двух частей.

1. FormTitle и FormDescription обычные input поля.
2. А BlockWorkingFieldForm представляет из себя блок (input, chexbox и select), которой можно добавлять сколько угодно раз (добавление происходит снизу формы, т.е. не произвольно) и удалять созданные блоки в произвольном порядке. При этом хотя бы один блок BlockWorkingFieldForm должен присутствовать.
   Ну и собственно при нажатии на кнопку Отправить, форма должна отправиться на сервер и заполнить модель.

На клиентской части только jQuery, но можно использовать и другие инструменты, если это поможет решить задачу.

Я конечно нашел способ один описанный в этой статье (https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/), но статье уже 10 лет, есть ли другие способы?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать `razor` в представлении.Таким образом, можно создавать динамические страницы.

1) Для начала создайте промежуточную модель для вашего представления, например `MyViewModel`

```
 public class MyViewModel
    {
        public FormModel FormModel { get; set; }
        public BlockWorkingFieldForm BlockWorkingFieldForm { get; set; }
        public List<BlockWorkingFieldForm> listBlockWorkingFieldForm = new List<BlockWorkingFieldForm>();
    }
```

Используя модель `MyViewModel`, вы передадите 2 модели на ваше представление + коллекцию, в которую надо будет положить все `BlockWorkingFieldForm`.

2) Далее по нажатию кнопки добавляйте данные, а с помощью `foreach` выводите коллекцию на представлении.

```
@{
    foreach(BlockWorkingFieldForm item in listBlockWorkingFieldForm)
    {  
        . . .
        ваши input, chexbox и select
        например <input asp-for="@item.FieldHeader"/>
        . . .
    }
}
```